# Is there a way to disable table row blur ( tr.blur ) from a 3rd party website using DOM editor?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, view-source, ublock-origin

Is it possible to diable tr.blur using DOM filters ? I tried using ublock origins extension. I could diable the whole row or entry but not the blur only. I want to know if it is possible from a browser to remove tr.blue from a website.

[image]

I tried using ublock to block the specified tr.blur but when i disable it disables the td also i can't disable just the blur.

Edit: I used Webdeveloper toolbar to diable CSS. It does remove the blur revealing some details but not all. There were other arrangement to hide some information.

Comment: blur is most likely a CSS setting you can disable from the Dev Console. However, this only works (as any hack) if the website is poorly coded without backend validation and logic.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this could help but you can refer to it.

I just setup an CSS to blur the data.

Here:

```css
.dataBlur {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 8px #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Instrument Symbol</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>LTP</th>
        <th>Val</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="dataBlur">
        <th>This is just a sample data 1.</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>30</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dataBlur">
        <th>This is just a sample data 2.</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>30</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="dataBlur">
        <th>This is just a sample data 3.</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>20</th>
        <th>30</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="text-align:left" colspan="3">Total</th>
        <th>16</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```